# Move HTML children elements out of parent and remove the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to move children outside of parent then remove the parent itself in vanilla JavaScript. Current code looks something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
```

Comment: lol currently code looks like this...there is no code..its your html.

Comment: Last I remember, HTML is code. I recreated a simplified version of what I have because I want to understand how to approach a situation like this.

Comment: Right ... but you said it as if you attempted some sort of client side code...you haven't attempted anything you posted static html.

Comment: I have attempted this in multiple ways in console and I got this to work prior to asking, but wanted a better approach. Is it now obligatory to post all scratch work? I'm trying to learn something I don't understand, posting my scrap work would make this an unnecessarily long post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `outerHTML` property to `innerHTML` property.

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML
```

See live demo:

```js
console.log('Before change: ', document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML)

const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML

console.log('After change: ', document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked thanks, why is it that by doing that, the outerHTML doesn't override any of the divs outside of the parent? This is what I want, I'm just curious because I would have thought that the new content of the outer HTML would only be the children.

Comment: @AoC `element.innerHTML` is the content of the element. `element.outerHTML` is the content of the element plus the element itself. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as in the @MichałPerłakowski answer using `. outerHTML` and `. innerHTML`, which is ok if you are not critical about speed (parsing HTML into DOM nodes) and do not care about attached event listeners, etc.

More efficient and resilient solution would be by juggling with dom elements:

```
while(parentElement.childNodes.length){
    parentElement.before(parentElement.childNodes[0]);
}
parentElement.remove();
```